# Unity3d Box Collider Vertex

Tags: transform, local, unity-game-engine

How do I get the vertexes of a box collider in world space in Unity3d? (with correct rotation and scale).  Just doing local-world on the object does not work.

obj.transform.localToWorldMatrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(extents); and doing similar things for the other corners is what I tried.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific with your needs.  Bounds are axis aligned so rotations aren't really relevant.  Bounds change to maintain a correct bounding box for your object.  When you rotate said object the bounds don't just rotate with it as this wouldn't result in a proper AABB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can easily get the [BoxCollider's *centre* and *extents*](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Bounds.html) you can get the local vertex position easily by adding or subtracting the extent from the centre, then transforming it into global world space with a method like [Vector3.TransformPoint()](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html)

The following script prints the global position of each vertex of a BoxCollider attached to the same GameObject as the script, every Update() call.

```
using System.Collections;
public class DebugPrintColliderVertices : MonoBehaviour
{
const uint NUM_VERTICES = 8;

private BoxCollider boxCollider;
private Transform[] vertices;

void Awake()
{
    boxCollider = (BoxCollider)this.gameObject.GetComponent(typeof(BoxCollider));

    if (boxCollider ==  null)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Collider not found on " + this.gameObject.name + ". Ending script.");   
        this.enabled = false;
    }

    vertices = new Transform[NUM_VERTICES];
}

void Update()
{
    Vector3 colliderCentre  = boxCollider.center;
    Vector3 colliderExtents = boxCollider.extents;

    for (int i = 0; i != NUM_VERTICES ; ++i)
    {
        Vector3 extents = colliderExtents;

        extents.Scale (new Vector3((i & 1) == 0 ? 1 : -1, (i & 2) == 0 ? 1 : -1, (i & 4) == 0 ? 1 : -1));

        Vector3 vertexPosLocal = colliderCentre + extents;

        Vector3 vertexPosGlobal = boxCollider.transform.TransformPoint(vertexPosLocal);

        // display vector3 to six decimal places
        Debug.Log ("Vertex " + i + " @ " + vertexPosGlobal.ToString("F6"));
    }       
}
}
```

Note that the BoxCollider's size is multiplied by the transform.scale of the GameObject it's attached to. I haven't included that calculation in said script, but finding the overall rotation/scale should be fairly trivial from this point.

Comment: GetCompnent is a method of Component.  this.gameObject is redundant.  You're also not using the generic for of GetComponent.  Make it look like this:
boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
Additionally, "vertice" is not a word.

Comment: GetComponent is also a method of GameObject [link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html). I'm aware that it's redundant referring to this.gameObject but opted to show it as an association of the gameObject this script is attached to, in case the user asking the question was unfamiliar with it's association.